# _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>

Tags: json, flutter, dart

hi I am still learning flutter and I am struggling to understand and fix this problem.

I am using dio to retrieve data from api to pass it to repository then to the cubit and then the ui.

when ever I press button that takes me to screen that suppose to show data that come api.

gives me this error.

debug counsel

```
flutter: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>'
```

Json respons

```
{
"chapters": [
       {
        "id": 114,
        "revelation_place": "makkah",
        "revelation_order": 21,
        "bismillah_pre": true,
        "name_simple": "An-Nas",
        "name_complex": "An-Nās",
        "name_arabic": "الناس",
        "verses_count": 6,
        "pages": [
            604,
            604
        ],
        "translated_name": {
            "language_name": "english",
            "name": "Mankind"
        }
    }
]}
```

my model

```
class ChapterModel {
  List<Chapters>? chapters;

  ChapterModel({this.chapters});

  ChapterModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['chapters'] != null) {
      chapters = <Chapters>[];
      json['chapters'].forEach((v) {
        chapters!.add(new Chapters.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}

class Chapters {
  int? id;
  String? revelationPlace;
  int? revelationOrder;
  bool? bismillahPre;
  String? nameSimple;
  String? nameComplex;
  String? nameArabic;
  int? versesCount;
  List<int>? pages;
  TranslatedName? translatedName;

  Chapters(
      {this.id,
      this.revelationPlace,
      this.revelationOrder,
      this.bismillahPre,
      this.nameSimple,
      this.nameComplex,
      this.nameArabic,
      this.versesCount,
      this.pages,
      this.translatedName});

  Chapters.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    revelationPlace = json['revelation_place'];
    revelationOrder = json['revelation_order'];
    bismillahPre = json['bismillah_pre'];
    nameSimple = json['name_simple'];
    nameComplex = json['name_complex'];
    nameArabic = json['name_arabic'];
    versesCount = json['verses_count'];
    pages = json['pages'].cast<int>();
    translatedName = json['translated_name'] != null
        ? new TranslatedName.fromJson(json['translated_name'])
        : null;
  }
}
```

my dio

```
class ApinWebServices {
  static late Dio dio;

  static init() {
    BaseOptions options = BaseOptions(
      baseUrl: baseUrl,
      queryParameters: {'language': 'ar'},
      receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
    );

    dio = Dio(options);
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> getALLJuzQuran() async {
    try {
      Response response = await dio.get('chapters');
      return response.data;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return [];
    }
  }
}
```

my repository

```
class ChapterRepository {
  final ApinWebServices apinWebServices;

  ChapterRepository(this.apinWebServices);

  Future<List<ChapterModel>> getALLJuzQuran() async {
    final juzQuran = await apinWebServices.getALLJuzQuran();


    return juzQuran.map((e) => ChapterModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
}
```

my cubit

```
class JuzquranCubit extends Cubit<HomeState> {
  final ChapterRepository chapterRepository;

  late List<ChapterModel> juzQuran = [];
  JuzquranCubit(this.chapterRepository) : super(HomeInitial());

  List<ChapterModel> getALLJuzQuran() {
    chapterRepository.getALLJuzQuran().then((chapters) {
      emit(JuzQuranLoaded(chapters: chapters));
      this.juzQuran = juzQuran;
    });
    return juzQuran;


  }
}
```

Comment: On the Dio side return make it **return response.data['chapters'];** since it's a raw data so that from the **return juzQuran.map((e) => ChapterModel.fromJson(e)).toList();** you might able to put them in model try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ApinWebServices, you are using

```
Dio.get('chapters');
```

which is not a property of `Dio`, as your data is json use

```
return response.data['chapters'];
```